# How to login Desktop without being interrupted by ctrl+c?

Tags: desktop-environments, openbox, .profile

I made a ubuntu system from ubuntu server by adding xong and openbox on it.

I also edited .profile to auto login X, so I can power on and wait a few seconds , then it's in the openbox desktop.

But if I continuously press ctrl+c durning bootup , it will stop at the console.
I tried to disable ctrl+c but it doesn't work during bootup.

Anyone knows about it?

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Blangero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable `ctrl-c` in a terminal by:

```
stty intr undef
```

and reenable it by:

```
stty intr ^c
```

So, you can put this line in .profile of the auto login user, or is that what you already tried?

Comment: I've tried something like that .... I just added stty intr undef and echo 1 >> /count_profile,reboot and press ctrl+c ,it stops at shell and there's no count_profile at / . So it seems that ctrl+c interrupt something before ~/.profile is used.

Comment: Ok, the shell that is used during the boot time is `dash`, and this shell reads the file `/etc/profile`, not your users .profile, so write the stty-command in this file. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Yes , it do works!! I tried several times and ctrl+c didn't interrupt logging into X . Thanks so much ! 
BTW, it should be kept in the file or if it is removed , next reboot and bootup ctrl+c works again.